# Canon powerpoint sx240HS usb port broken

Tags: canon

Yesterday I tried to download some photographs from my camera via the usb port only to find that the usb port was broken(no problem) so I downloaded the photos from a card reader. However this morning my camera powered up but live view had a black screen. Preview and menu buttons also gives a black screen.Shutter button and  flash sound OK. Could a broken usb port cause damage and cause black live view? And is it worth having it repaired? Thank you

Comment: This really isnt a photography question, but I will at least try to be helpful - to answer your question, yes, if the port has bent pins, they could be shorting and causing all manner of internal confusion.

Comment: How did the USB port become broken?

Comment: My guess ..... it got broken when inserting or pulling cord from Port.  Camera was working perfectly the morning before. Pity, it was a good compact camera with manual settings. Good thing I have a Nikon D3300...which is bulkier...time to practice using it. Thank u for your replies,

Answer (score 1):

For the price it's probably not worth getting fixed. They would probably replace the usb port. Which if your lucky they'll only charge 50 or 60 bucks. Then they'll check the screen and you'll be looking at more towards the 100 to 150 dollar range ( on the low end ) if the screen is bad. So at that point your better off with a new one. If you have any soldering skills you might be able to repair it yourself though. Ifixit should have a tutorial for a similar repair.

Comment: No soldering skills, I'm afraid ...☹. Thank u for your reply.